# use python3 to get information from a txt file whose style is lists and tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a file "test.txt". Its data is in the following style:

```
[(5.0, 1.12, 1, ((False, []), 0.85)), (4.21, 3.2, 2, ((True, []), 0.7997))]\n
```

This example only shows the first row in the file, the file has actually 20 rows.

In each row, it starts with "[" and ends with "]" (note that the "\n" is just a new line symbol.).
As you can see, the pattern in each row is "[(  ((  )  ) ), (  ((  )  ) ), ...]". In real case, there are 10000 "(  ((  )  ) )" within one "[ ]".

Do you know how to read this information using python3?

The result I want is

```
x_row1 = [[5.0, 1.12, 1],
          [4.21, 3.2, 2],
          ...,
         ]  # len(x_row1) == 10000
y_row1 = [[False, []], 0.85],
          [True, []], 0.7997],
          ...,
         ]  # len(y_row1) == 10000

x_row_all = [[x_row1], [x_row2], ..., [x_row20]]
y_row_all = [[y_row1], [y_row2], ..., [y_row20]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided **may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`.**

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[(5.0, 1.12, 1, ((False, []), 0.85)), (4.21, 3.2, 2, ((True, []), 0.7997))]\n')
[(5.0, 1.12, 1, ((False, []), 0.85)), (4.21, 3.2, 2, ((True, []), 0.7997))]
```

For your specific problem:

```
import ast

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    all_rows = list(map(ast.literal_eval, f))

x_row_all = [[item[:3] for item in row] for row in all_rows]
y_row_all = [[item[-1] for item in row] for row in all_rows]
```

If you really need the tuples to become lists do instead:

```
def detuple(tup):
    return [detuple(x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else x for x in tup]

x_row_all = [[list(item[:3]) for item in row] for row in all_rows]
# tup = ((False, []), 0.85); detuple(tup) => [[False, []], 0.85]
y_row_all = [[detuple(item[-1]) for item in row] for row in all_rows]
```

Alternatively you can have lists from the beginning if you create `all_rows` as:

```
all_rows = [ast.literal_eval(line.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']') for line in f]
```